# Self-signed certificates ok for kubernetes validating webhooks?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, webhooks, self-signed-certificate

I'm trying to understand the security implications for using self-signed certificates for a Kubernetes validating webhook.

If I'm understanding correctly, the certificate is simply used to be able to serve the validating webhook server over https.  When the Kubernetes api-server receives a request that matches the configuration for a validating webhook, it'll first check with the validating webhook server over https.  If your validating webhook server lives on the Kubernetes cluster (is not external) then this traffic is all internal to a Kubernetes cluster.  If this is the case is it problematic that the cert is self-signed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I'm understanding correctly, the certificate is simply used to be
> able to serve the validating webhook server over https.

Basically yes.

> If your validating webhook server lives on the Kubernetes cluster (is
> not external) then this traffic is all internal to a Kubernetes
> cluster. If this is the case is it problematic that the cert is
> self-signed?

If the issuing process is handled properly and in secure manner, self-signed certs shouldn't be a problem at all. Compare with [this](https://gist.github.com/tirumaraiselvan/b7eb1831d25dd9d59a785c11bd46c84b) example.

Comment: what i'm hearing then is that it's ok to run a production deployment like this, and that I'm not opening myself up to any security concerns - is that true?

Comment: Of course, if it serves for internal communication it doesn't really matter if it's self-signed certificate or a certificate signed by some trusted authority. The traffic is encrypted in the same way.

Comment: Sounds like a common use case. What's the standard way to keep the certificate renewed? Why do people rewrite this unrelated logic themselves just to get a simple callback going?

Comment: @Velkan pretty much everyone uses cert-manager.  adding https to internal communications is recommended to keep security information gathering lower.  someone can't sniff an api for example.  you could do it all with http and let a service mesh do all of your encryption, let platform team manage a mesh (isitio, linkerd, traefik)